Add css file with `$this->Html->css()` from an element not working in cakephp
I'm trying to add a specific css file from an element to the layout in cakephp but the file doesn't appear in the source code.
However it works from a static page.
// In the layout
echo $this->element('diaporama_accueil');

// In templates/element/diaporama_accueil.php [NOT WORKING] 
$this->Html->css('subtle-slideshow.css', ['block' => true]);

// In templates/Pages/accueil.php [WORKING]
$this->Html->css('subtle-slideshow.css', ['block' => true]);


What's the problem with doing that in an element ?

After a lot of tests, it seems that the problem happens only when I do echo $this->element('diaporama_accueil') inside the layout.
In that case the element diaporama_accueil doesn't to return the css to the layout.
But when I call the same echo $this->element('diaporama_accueil') from any template else, the element diaporama_accueil returns the css to the layout as expected...
(But I don't know why)
